# annotation based Spring bean validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-modules

I'm investigating an annotation-based approach to validating Spring beans using [spring modules](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/). In [this tutorial](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-bean-validation-framework.html), the following bean (getters and setters omitted) is used as an example:

```
public final class User {  

  @NotBlank  
  @Length(max = 80)  
  private String name;  

  @NotBlank  
  @Email  
  @Length(max = 80)  
  private String email;  

  @NotBlank  
  @Length(max = 4000)  
  private String text;  
}
```

The error message that is used if a particular validation rule is disobeyed should follow this format:

```
bean-class.bean-propery[validation-rule]=Validation Error message
```

Examples for the class shown above include:

```
User.email[not.blank]=Please enter your e-mail address.  
User.email[email]=Please enter a valid e-mail address.  
User.email[length]=Please enter no more than {2} characters.
```

The fact that the message keys contain the class name presents a couple of problems:

1. If the class is renamed, the message keys also need to be changed
2. If I have another class (e.g. Person) with an email property that is validated identically to User.email, I need to duplicate the messages, e.g.

   Person.email[not.blank]=Please enter your e-mail address.
   Person.email[email]=Please enter a valid e-mail address.
   Person.email[length]=Please enter no more than {2} characters.

In fact, the documentation claims that is possible to configure a default message for a particular rule (e.g. @Email) like this:

```
email=email address is invalid
```

This default message should be used if a bean-specific message for the rule cannot be found. However, my experience is that this simply does not work.

An alternative mechanism for avoiding duplicate messages is to pass the key of the error message to the rule annotation. For example, assume I have defined the following default error message for the @Email rule

```
badEmail=Email address is invalid
```

This message should be used if I annotate the relevant property like this:

```
@Email(errorCode="badEmail")
private String email;
```

However I tried this, out and again, it just doesn't seem to work. Has anyone found a way to avoid duplicating error messages when using this validation framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a quick look at the [BeanValidator API](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/source/browse/%2Acheckout%2A/springmodules/www/docs/javadocs/0.8/org/springmodules/validation/bean/BeanValidator.html), and it looks like you might want to try the *errorCodeConverter* property.

You would need to implement your own [ErrorCodeConverter](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/source/browse/%2Acheckout%2A/springmodules/www/docs/javadocs/0.8/org/springmodules/validation/bean/converter/ErrorCodeConverter.html), or use one of the provided implementations?

```
....
<bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator"
    p:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader"
    p:errorCodeConverter-ref="errorCodeConverter" />

<bean id="errorCodeConverter" class="contact.MyErrorCodeConverter" />
....
```

*Note: configurationLoader is another bean defined in the config XML used in the tutorial*

Example converter:

```
package contact;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.converter.ErrorCodeConverter;

public class MyErrorCodeConverter implements ErrorCodeConverter {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyErrorCodeConverter.class);

    @Override
    public String convertPropertyErrorCode(String errorCode, Class clazz, String property) {
        log.error(String.format("Property %s %s %s", errorCode, clazz.getClass().getName(), property));
        return errorCode;  // <------ use the errorCode only
    }

    @Override
    public String convertGlobalErrorCode(String errorCode, Class clazz) {
        log.error(String.format("Global %s %s", errorCode, clazz.getClass().getName()));
        return errorCode;
    }
}
```

Now the properties should work:

```
MyEmailErrorCode=Bad email

class Foo {
    @Email(errorCode="MyEmailErrorCode")
    String email
}
```

Comment: In the Spring config shown above, what is the configurationLoader bean?

Comment: Hi Don - I downloaded the source code from the tutorial website you mentioned, and configurationLoader is already one of the beans defined in their config xml. When I get home and look at the code I wrote, I can update this posting.

Comment: The configurationLoader bean from the tutorial is of type org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader

Answer (score 2):

Spring validation does have an ErrorCodeConverter that does this:

org.springmodules.validation.bean.converter.KeepAsIsErrorCodeConverter

When this is used, the resource bundle will be checked for the following codes:

[errorCode.commandBeanName.fieldName, errorCode.fieldName, errorCode.fieldClassName, errorCode]

- errorCode is the actual validation errorCode eg. not.blank, email.
- commandBeanName is the same as the model key name that references the
  form backing bean.
- fieldName is the name of the field.
- fieldClassName is the field class name eg. java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer

So for instance if I have a bean that is referenced in the model by the key "formBean" and the field emailAddress of type java.lang.String does not contain an email address, which causes the errorCode email. The validation framework will attempt to resolve the following message codes:

[email.formBean.emailAddress, email.emailAddress, email.java.lang.String, email]

If the errorCode is replaced by the errorCode "badEmail" like this:

@Email(errorCode="badEmail")

The messages codes that the framework will try resolve will be:

[badEmail.formBean.emailAddress, badEmail.emailAddress, badEmail.java.lang.String, badEmail]

I would suggest keeping the errodCode the same. Thus one message can be used for all fields that have that errorCode associated with them. If you need to be more specific with the message for a certain field you can add a message to the resource bundles with the code errorCode.commandBeanName.field.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following beans in your `applicationContext.xml` file.

```
<bean id="configurationLoader"
    class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader" />

<!-- Use the error codes as is. Don't convert them to <Bean class name>.<bean field being validated>[errorCode]. -->    
<bean id="errorCodeConverter"
    class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.converter.KeepAsIsErrorCodeConverter"/>

 <!-- shortCircuitFieldValidation = true ==> If the first rule fails on a field, no need to check 
    other rules for that field -->   
<bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator"
    p:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader"
    p:shortCircuitFieldValidation="true" 
    p:errorCodeConverter-ref="errorCodeConverter"/>
```